# Can I use Monaco to make changes to a Windows Azure Web Role?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-monaco

I have been using Visual Studio to manage and develop an application that runs on a Windows Azure web role.  It's an ASP.Net WebApi Application that connects to a backend SQL Azure Database. The code base is hosted on GitHub.

I have read about Monaco and its ability to edit Windows Azure Web Sites but I have not seen any references to the tool being used or able to be used to change a Web Role.

Is this possible with Monaco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is built into the Azure environment for Websites only. The deployment model for Web and Worker Roles differs substantially from that used for Websites.